# Issue in UITextField add inside UIImageView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uitextfield

Currently i am working in iPhone app, Using UIImageView to set a background image on the screen, then add UITextField inside the UIImageView, then i run the app, the UITextField cannot enabled, How to enable this? please help me

Thanks in Advance

I tried this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"2ndscreenback.png"];

Daystext =[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(57, 122, 171, 31)];
Daystext.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
Daystext.delegate=self;
Daystext.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[imageView addSubview:Daystext];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: Write Daystext.editable = YES;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add below line in your code

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Means like this

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"2ndscreenback.png"];

Daystext =[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(57, 122, 171, 31)];
Daystext.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
Daystext.delegate=self;
Daystext.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[imageView addSubview:Daystext];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"2ndscreenback.png"];
imageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

Daystext =[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(57, 122, 171, 31)];
Daystext.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
Daystext.delegate=self;

[imageView addSubview:Daystext];
```

you can get the textfield on imageview....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"2ndscreenback.png"];

Daystext =[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(57, 122, 171, 31)];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
Daystext.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
Daystext.delegate=self;
Daystext.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[self.view addSubview:Daystext];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to set background image for your UITextFild like this:

```
myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
myTextField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
```

or like this

```
UIImageView *myView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]];
[myTextField  setRightView:myView];
[myTextField  setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
```

Comment: she is not wanted to set background image to textfield.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what exactly she wants. I thought she wants to setup background image...

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"2ndscreenback.png"];

Daystext =[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(57, 122, 171, 31)];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
Daystext.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
Daystext.delegate=self;
Daystext.editable = YES;
Daystext.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[self.view addSubview:Daystext];
```

Try this. Hope it works for u !!!