# UIImage inside a UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitextfield

How can i place an image inside a `UITextField` like in **iMessages** or **Kik**?

[image]

Do i need to make a `UIView` with a `UITextInput` / `UITextField` and add a `UIImageView` as a subview?

I really don't know how to approach it.

Comment: how does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346269/issue-in-uitextfield-add-inside-uiimageview-in-iphone correlate to your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to make a UIView and add imageView as its subview.You can also use alternatives given here https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=chat

Comment: Can you give an example of how to place a UITextInput inside a a UIView because i need to be able to write text and add image in the same view. Non of the examples in CocoaControls has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these controls for this :

1. [uibubbletableview](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/uibubbletableview)
2. [bubblethingie](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/bubblethingie)

Comment: No, I think I didn't explain my self right, i need to add the image inside a TextField and no inside a normal bubble. My problem is combining a TextField and an ImageView