# How to add a UIImage into a text field - objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I am currently making an iphone application and i have a uitextbox with an attention image along side. 
Is there any way i  can add the image into the text box (to make it look neater).

Comment: post the code you have tried ? that will help us to find , how you are trying to implement it.

Comment: This question a possible duplicate of SO Question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019326/uiimage-inside-a-uitextfield) 1. Create Textfield programmatically 2. inside the text field add uiimage as subview